# How to center icons horizontally above text (no flexbox/grid)?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I am working on psd conversion and I need to center the font awesome icons horizontally above the text without using flexbox and grid. The ul that wraps them will be stacking vertically on mobile.

I need to accomplish this by using only css. Any help is appreciated.

```
 <div class="info-section">
      <!-- <div class="wrapper clearfix"> -->
        <section class="info-section-container">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Tickets</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class=info-link><i class="fas fa-phone contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Reach Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
```

```
/* this centers the entire container  */
 .info-section-container {
    /* width: 50%; */
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 25%;

  }

  /* to position the li horizontally */
  .info-section-container ul li {
    float: left;
  }

  .info-link  {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  /* for accesability */
  padding: 10px;
  /* width: 30%;
  display: inline-block; */
 }

  .contact-icons {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is centre all the `<li>` items and the icons, then you need very few changes. All you really need to do is add the following rules:

```
.info-section-container {  margin: 0 auto; }
.info-section-container ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; }
.info-link {  text-align: center; display: inline-block; /* and your own styles here */ }
.fas.contact-icons { display:block; }
```

**How these work:**

- The biggest problem is the left and right margins of 25%  on `info-section-container` - this is too big on mobile and the text doesn't fit, it juts out to the right.
  To centre the whole container use `margin: 0 auto;`. If you want to limit its size, you can use `max-width`
- `<ul>` elements have padding on the left which will affect the centre alignment, so you need to set it to 0
- Set your `info-link` elements to be inline-block and text-align center
- You need to include `.fas` in the `.contact-icons` selector to override the default CSS

**You can see this working below** - note I have added a media query for 650px so you can see it stacked here and horizontal in you view the snippet in expanded.

```css
/* this centers the entire container  */
.info-section-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info-section-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.info-section-container ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-link {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /* for accesability */
  padding: 10px;
}

.fa.contact-icons, /* for this demo only */
.fas.contact-icons {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
  .info-section-container ul li { display: block;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="info-section">
  <section class="info-section-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fa fa-ticket contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Tickets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class=info-link><i class="fa fa-phone contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Reach Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

*FYI I am using Font Awesone 4.7 above because 5 isn't available on a CDN. The main difference is the class is `.fa` instead of `.fas`*

Comment: This is great, I really appreciate it! It worked like a charm. Quick question regarding the .fas selector - which CSS rule are being overridden here. If i don't use it the icon still has the display: block rule but it doesn't actually work.

Comment: @KarmenSalim Glad to help! The reason `.contact-block {display:block}` isn't working in in this case is because the Font Awesome styles are being included *after* this CSS and overriding your display setting. By using `.fas.contact-block`, we are making the selector more specific so it isn't getting overridden. You can find out more about [CSS specificity here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

Answer (score 0):

add some flex container on your ul

```
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li><a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Tickets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class=info-link><i class="fas fa-phone contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Reach Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

and a couple of new flex classes

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-container li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

should make the icon above the text

Comment: I need to accomplish this with pure css, no flexbox.

Comment: @KarmenSalim flexbox *is* CSS...if there is a reason you don't want to use it, then you should mention it in your question, because otherwise it is a valid answer.

Comment: @KarmenSalim is there an old target browser that you need to support? if not as other have said, Flexbox is CSS. If you still doubt it, please do check https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox for compatibilty

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, I am working on a project for my course and they don't allow us to use flexbox only CSS and floats for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code as:

```css
.info-section-container {
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     left: 25%;
}

.info-link {
     width: 50vw;
     height: 30vh;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;

     margin-top: 5%;
     margin-bottom: 5%;
  
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 3rem;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-section">
        <div class="info-section-container">
            <a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Locations</a>
            <a href="#" class="info-link"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Tickets</a>
           <a href="#" class=info-link><i class="fas fa-phone contact-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>Reach Out</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

First, I adjusted width of info-link as 50vw. It covers the half of the width of screen. Therefore, it has 25% margin from both left and right. You want to center them, so I gave extra left which is 25% in absolute position and added justify-conter: center in .info-section-container to center the three texts horizontally.

I chose display as flex to have column flex direction.

Then, in .info-section-container, I added align-items: center to center vertically these three items.

Hope I helped.